# signingConfigs tag giving me a Lint error in build.gradle after upgrading to v22

Tags: android, groovy, android-studio, gradle, lint

I've had the following code in my build.gradle (app) file for a while:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("D:\\Android\\keystore\\myApp.jks")
        storePassword "myStorePw"
        keyAlias "myKeyAlias"
        keyPassword "MyKeyPw"
    }
}
```

I've just upgraded to targetSdkVersion=22, which meant upgrading SDKs and build tools to 22 as well.  Now that whole section is highlighted in yellow in Android Studio (141.1793788) with the message:

```
'signingConfigs' cannot be applied to '(groovy.land.Closure<com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig>)'
```

Has there been a change in v22 that I need to know about? I can't find documentation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please try to move your signingConfigs section higher, just below: *compileSdkVersion* and *buildToolsVersion*. Example below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("D:\\Android\\keystore\\myApp.jks")
            storePassword "myStorePw"
            keyAlias "myKeyAlias"
            keyPassword "MyKeyPw"
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was helpful to me, but can you explain why?

Comment: @GDanger fyi: I just explained in answer why.

Answer (score 7):

As @GDanger asked for the reason; So the reason is simple. When you define a variable in gradle script, keep that in mind, It should not be used before its definition.

I am pretty much sure that OP has defined the `signingConfigs` below `buildType` config. And because of that he is getting that warning message.

Let's do an experiment to understand; write below code in your gradle script:

```
def A = B;
def B = "I am test."
```

You'll see this error when you syn with gradle:

```
Error:(3, 0) Could not find property 'B' on project ':app'.
<a href="openFile">Open File</a>
```

But when you define it like this:

```
def B = "I am test."
def A = B;
```

You'll not get any error. So I am sure trying this small experiment would make you understand that how compiling in gradle script works. Hope this will help. :)

Comment: This helps, but what in `defaultConfig {minSdkVersion 12 ...}` refers to something defined by `signingConfigs {releaseSigning { ... }}`? It's not visible, and it used to work.

Comment: @Jerry101 What do you mean exactly? defaultConfig has common attributes, which will be used for every flavor. Whereas SigningConfigs contains attributes specific to release and debug flavor only.

Comment: My build.gradle had `compileSdkVersion 24; buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'; defaultConfig {minSdkVersion 12; targetSdkVersion 24; versionCode 14; versionName "2.4"; ...}; signingConfigs {releaseSigning {storeFile ... }}`. The switch to SDK+tools 24 caused the `'signingConfigs' cannot be applied to ...Closure` error. Moving signingConfigs before defaultConfig fixed the error (thank you both)! I wouldn't guess the error meant "reference before use", and there are no identifiers in common between the two sections. So the problem is fixed but I don't understand how.